# What are common issues with sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've been considering using node/express/sequelize for a project but I've read in a few places where people strongly advise against using sequelize as an ORM. Can someone advise me on the major reasons why people say not to use sequelize?

For clarity, I'm using postgres as a database for relational data, not no-sql

Answer (score 1):

It happens to be that MySQL is not part of the opinionated MEAN Stack. There was a revolution against the strict schema types of SQL, and started a NoSQL revolution. MongoDB earned its position in the MEAN stack, and the rest is history. As far as I'm concerned, it's just an opinion. If you need strictly structured data and your backend uses MySQL, you'll be fine, don't listen to all the hype man. Remember, these are tools we are using.